# 3x3 box blur in C: last row

Tags: c, pixel

I'm trying to do that box blur in C. My strategy is to store the actual pixel values in a copy and replace the image pixels by the average RGB calculated based on the copy's values. So I check for the existence of an above pixel, below pixel, [height - 1][width - 1] pixel etc., if true, I add the RGB values to a sum and increase the count.

The issue is with the last row of pixels, which is filled with garbage values when I printf `copy[height][width]`. I've tried stopping the loop at [height - 1], and to switch the order by filling the copy with the averaged pixels and then replacing the image's pixels by the copy's pixels. When I switch the order of the steps, the last row appears darker than the rest of the pic.
Not sure what I'm missing here. Is it because I'm assuming the existence of the middle pixel?

(Please don't refer to previous answers, I've tried out a couple from here which return seg faults and the goal of the exercise is to reuse as much of my input as possible)

Sorry for the poor indentation.

Thankie

```
 #include "math.h"
 #include "stdio.h"

void blur(int height, int width, RGBTRIPLE image[height][width])
{

    // Create a copy to avoid overwriting
RGBTRIPLE copy[height][width];
for (int i = 0; i < height ; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < width; j++)
    {
        copy[i][j].rgbtRed = image[i][j].rgbtRed;
        copy[i][j].rgbtGreen = image[i][j].rgbtGreen;
        copy[i][j].rgbtBlue = image[i][j].rgbtBlue;

    }
}



for (int h = 0; h < height; h++)
{
    for (int w = 0; w < width; w++)
    {
        int red_sum = copy[h][w].rgbtRed;
        int green_sum = copy[h][w].rgbtGreen;
        int blue_sum = copy[h][w].rgbtBlue;
        int count = 1;

        // If not on top row, add pixel above
        if (h > 0)
        {
            red_sum += copy[h - 1][w].rgbtRed;
            green_sum += copy[h - 1][w].rgbtGreen;
            blue_sum += copy[h - 1][w].rgbtBlue;
            count++;
        }
        // If not on bottom row, add pixel below
        if (h < height)
        {
            red_sum += copy[h + 1][w].rgbtRed;
            green_sum += copy[h + 1][w].rgbtGreen;
            blue_sum += copy[h + 1][w].rgbtBlue;
            count++;
        }
        // Not left column
        if (w > 0)
        {
            red_sum += copy[h][w - 1].rgbtRed;
            green_sum += copy[h][w - 1].rgbtGreen;
            blue_sum += copy[h][w - 1].rgbtBlue;
            count++;
        }
        // Not right column
        if (w < width)
        {
            red_sum += copy[h][w + 1].rgbtRed;
            green_sum += copy[h][w + 1].rgbtGreen;
            blue_sum += copy[h][w + 1].rgbtBlue;
            count++;
        }
        // Not top left hand corner
        if (h > 0 && w > 0)
        {
            red_sum += copy[h - 1][w - 1].rgbtRed;
            green_sum += copy[h - 1][w - 1].rgbtGreen;
            blue_sum += copy[h - 1][w - 1].rgbtBlue;
            count++;
        }
        // Not top right hand corner
        if (h > 0 && w < width)
        {
            red_sum += copy[h - 1][w + 1].rgbtRed;
            green_sum += copy[h - 1][w + 1].rgbtGreen;
            blue_sum += copy[h - 1][w + 1].rgbtBlue;
            count++;
        }
        // Not bottom left hand corner
        if (h < height && w > 0)
        {
            red_sum += copy[h + 1][w - 1].rgbtRed;
            green_sum += copy[h + 1][w - 1].rgbtGreen;
            blue_sum += copy[h + 1][w - 1].rgbtBlue;
            count++;
        }
        // Not bottom right hand corner
        if (h < height && w < width)
        {
            red_sum += copy[h + 1][w + 1].rgbtRed;
            green_sum += copy[h + 1][w + 1].rgbtGreen;
            blue_sum += copy[h + 1][w + 1].rgbtBlue;
            count++;
        }
    
        int average_red = round(red_sum / (float)count);
        int average_green = round(green_sum / (float)count);
        int average_blue = round(blue_sum / (float)count);
    

        image[h][w].rgbtRed = average_red;
        image[h][w].rgbtGreen = average_green;
        image[h][w].rgbtBlue = average_blue;

    }
}
return;
}
```

Comment: `if (h < height)` -> `if (h + 1 < height)`, etc. - you need to check if the adjusted value will be in bounds

Comment: You are creating copy as a local automatic which will stackoverflow for a large enough image.

Comment: Okay but then do I need to check for `w + 1 < width` as well? [Thx, I figured out the answer is yes]